# Kafka Admin: how to show and set the retention time per topic programmatically?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to programmatically (Java) get and set the retention time of some set of topics in a Kafka cluster.

It does not seem to be possible using `org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient`.

Is there any other way apart from command line utilities?

Comment: Have you tried the `describeTopics` method?

Comment: Yes, and it returns a `DescribeTopicsResult` that includes a `Map<String, KafkaFuture<TopicDescription>>`. `TopicDescription`, apart from `name` and the `internal` flag, include a `TopicPartitionInfo`, which in turn just includes the `int` of the partition and `leader`, `replicas`, and `isr` fields, i.e. a bunch of `Node`s information that doesn't have much to do with retention times and the like.

Answer (score 1):

To emulate `kafka-configs --entity-type topics --entity-name "topic" --describe`, you should be able to use `AdminClient#describeConfigs` simlar to this.

Here, I filter out for only configurations that have been explictily defined by a user. If you remove the filter, you will get all the topic-level and broker-level default configs as well

```
Optional<List<ConfigEntry>> dynamicTopicConfigEntries;

try {
    // given org.apache.kafka.client.admin.AdminClient
    ConfigResource resource = new ConfigResource(ConfigResource.Type.TOPIC, "topic");

    dynamicTopicConfigEntries = Optional.of(adminClient.describeConfigs(Collections.singletonList(resource))
            .all()
            .thenApply(configMap -> configMap.get(resource).entries()
                    .stream().filter(e -> e.source() == ConfigEntry.ConfigSource.DYNAMIC_TOPIC_CONFIG)
                    .collect(toList())
            )
            .get());
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to get topic description");
}
```

Similarly, there is an `--alter` flag that is supported for that command (don't have code available for it)

Also, [KIP-248](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-248+-+Create+New+ConfigCommand+That+Uses+The+New+AdminClient) is one to watch.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `kafka.admin.TopicCommand` scala class, which is what the `kafka-topics` shell script uses from the Kafka binary distribution:

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/a421dd2a26ca140f821cd5be1a4f716cf04beb43/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/TopicCommand.scala#L302-L318

You can use that, although you'd need to include the kafka package as a dependency on your project, not only the Kafka clients.

Something like this if you're using Kafka 2.1.1, compiled for Scala 2.12:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.12/2.1.1

Comment: `AdminClient` is available in `kafka-clients` and should be able to get this information too. The `kafka.admin` package is mostly deprecated